# setInterval keeps doing the wrong if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a React hook to build a countdown timer and I want to use a setInterval() to decrease the time but at first it does the correct if statement (the last one) but then it keeps doing it even tough it's wrong. I tried console logging "seconds" and "minutes" and the browser keeps saying 25 and 0 (as I set them initially) even tough when I press the start button I can see the minutes showing another number.

the full code : https://pastebin.com/bHyuLGn2
The code which I say is relevant:

```js
const [timeleft, setTimeLeft] = useState({
    minutes: 25,
    seconds: 0,
});
const {
    minutes,
    seconds
} = timeleft;

function handleStart() {
    setStartButton(!startButton);

    setInterval(() => {

        if (seconds > 0) {
            setTimeLeft((prevValue) => {
                return {
                    ...prevValue,
                    seconds: prevValue.seconds - 1,
                };
            });
        } else if (seconds === 0) {
            if (minutes === 0) {
                clearInterval();
            } else {
                setTimeLeft((prevValue) => {
                    return {
                        minutes: prevValue.minutes - 1,
                        seconds: 59,
                    };
                });


            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: SetInterval is not accurate.... FYI

Answer (score 0):

No, `setInterval` is doing the correct thing actually, but your code is probably not doing what you want it to do.

Inside your interval, you are calling `setTimeLeft`. `setTimeLeft` causes the component to re-render, and your `setInterval` to reset every single time.

If you want to do what you're trying to do, you're likely going to have to pull that state out into its own hook, or architect this differently.

Answer (score 0):

You using setInterval wrong, because it should be like this:

```
let myInterval = setInterval(() => {/* bla-bla-bla */}, 1000)
// ...
clearInterval(myInterval)
```

but in you code I see this:

```
setInterval(() => {/* bla-bla-bla */}, 1000)
// ...
clearInterval()
```

so, clear **WHAT** interval?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with setInterval in react is that usually it makes the component render again, and the new render will call a new setInterval.

Here's an interesting article that provides a solution:

https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/